# Android TCP Connection: accept() not working

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I am building an Android app using TCP connection. Below is my TCP server code. When i test, it doesn't have any errors but the app has error

> "unfortunately app has stopped".

When i check the code it stucks at:"

`s=serverClient.accept();`

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.truong.total;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Created by duy on 26/10/2017.
 */

public class TCPServer {
    int port;
    String result;
    ServerSocket serverClient;
    TextView tv5;
    MainActivity at;
    public TCPServer(int newPort,MainActivity at) {
        this.port=newPort;
        this.at=at;
        try{
            serverClient=new ServerSocket(port);
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("constructornethanglol","1");
        //Log.d("constructornethanglol","1");
    }
    public void setConnection() {
        tv5=(TextView)at.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        Log.d("thanglol","2");
        try {
            Log.d("lol3","3");
            while (true) {
                Log.d("lol4","4");
                Socket s;
                Log.d("thanglol1","socket");

                //stuck
                s=serverClient.accept();


                Log.d("lol5","5");
                BufferedReader inFromClient =
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                this.result = inFromClient.readLine();
                tv5.setText("lol");
                s.close(); // sau khi dat. trong while
            }
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public String getResult() {
        return this.result;
    }
}
```

Can you show me where am i wrong? Thank you. Sorry for my bad English, it's not my first language.

Comment: You can try this tutorial https://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2013/03/31/android-tcp-connection-enhanced/#.WfLE7BOCxTY

Comment: can you share your log what error it prints?

Answer (score 0):

You should use networking related stuffs in a background thread. Either use `AsyncTask` or a `Thread`.

```
new Thread(new Runnable(
    public void run(){
        //your code.
    }
)).start();
```

You can view an example at 
https://github.com/nabinbhandari/android-socket-messaging